# Pivot tables: Choosing table range or data source connection. Differences in both

Tags: excel

Excel 2010.
Pivot tables:

Can someone clarify the diffrences (and pros and cons) in selecting a data range or selecting an external data source when creating a pivot table?

I have a SQL query that I want to show in excel. I need the data details and multiple pivots. I'm not sure if I should create one table and connect my pivots to that table or create multiple pivot connections.

There will be a weekly refresh of the data in SQL.

If I create a table range and my data is updated in SQL and refreshed with more rows then I selected for my range will my pivot table capture those new rows?

Comment: As long as your data is less than the # of rows Excel can hold you can safely place it in a worksheet. However, getting the data into the pivottable directly will mean a smaller filesize.
Depending on how your pivottables differ you can have them share the same data connection (PivotCache is the word) so that would be quite efficient. But if you need different groupings (for example, one grouped to show months and another to show Quarters) then each will need its own cache.

Comment: @jkpieterse  If I create a table range pivot and my data is updated in SQL and refreshed with more rows in the table then I selected for my original range, will my pivot table capture those new rows?

Comment: Yes because Tables in Excel (a SQL query is always tied to a "table")automatically ensure anything that connects to it (like a pivot table, a chart or formulas) automatically grows and shrinks with the data.